# rerouting node.js application (Ghost)

Tags: node.js, iis, ghost-blog, iisnode

I have Ghost blogging platform running in IIS through iisnode.

I want IIS to redirect/rewrite the default path / to something like this /tag/sometag/ so that when someone enters the blog, the site will show the first post under the tag.

In other words I want http://myblog.com/ to be equivalent to http://myblog.com/tag/sometag/.

The trick is that Ghost is a node.js application so I already have a rewrite rule to get ghost to handle the request. The rule is this one:

So all request are passed through and handled by index.js endpoint.

I'm really do not now how to achieve that and so far I read I haven't found something that could help me.

Thank you in advance for you help/

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your rule, but I think this is what you're looking for.

Within /ghost/core/server/routes/frontend.js change:

```
router.get('/', frontend.homepage);
```

to

```
router.get('/', frontend.newfunction);
```

Then in /ghost/core/server/controllers/frontend.js after:

```
frontendControllers = {
```

add:

```
newfunction: function(req, res, next) {
    return res.redirect(config.paths.subdir+'/[the path]/[you want]/')
},
```